# How to display content from a mysql database for a record selected from a drop down list

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched this forum for over a week trying to find a solution to my problem.  I can display the correct information if I enter a value in a text box but if I select the option in a dropdown list it only shows the last record.  Following is my latest code, can someone help me correct this code so the selected information is displayed? I've only included the segment affected.

```
<form id="selected" name="selected" method="get" action="" >
    <select name="id">

        <?php
        $result = $conn->query("select * from agreement");
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            unset($id, $name, $ctpd, $hsprogram);
            $id = $row['ID'];
            $name = $row['HSName'];
            $ctpd = $row['CTPD'];
            $hsprogram = $row['HSProgram'];
            echo '<option value="'.$id.'"' .$selected . '>'.$name.' </option>';

        }
        ?> 
    </select>

    <tr>

        <td>   <?php echo $ctpd ?> </td>
        <td>   <?php echo $name ?> </td>
        <td>   <?php echo $hsprogram ?> </td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Most likely it's the `$selected`-variable, which you're not showing making ALL the options "selected", which will only pass the last one through. Fix your code, or at least provide the full code for the form.

Comment: Come on luv, you spend a week trying to fix it and then you give us a quarter of the story and expect us to fix it! Show all relevant code, or an example that demonstrates the same issue